# Using variable resistor to nullify Cap Bank Droop

Tags: power-electronics, electronic-load

In a high power application I am charging a cap bank to 800V and letting it discharge into a load of about 2 ohms for 2 seconds.   To avoid droop I could overcharge the capacitors and use a buck converter or use some other power converter with PWM control. However, I believe this would create a lot of electrical noise at these current levels.

Is there an electronic load that I could put in series with the current load that would regulate current?  Basically decreasing from something like 1 ohm at the start of the 2 second period to short circuit at the end of the load. I am wondering if there is a strategy or product for doing this, especially for a system requiring 100s of amps.

Comment: Uh… have you run the numbers on the amount of power you'd be dissipating in this load?

Comment: It's called a linear regulator and they are very inefficient as they bleed off the excess voltage as heat so it would run VERY hot in your case. In your case, the power level is so high that you would have to roll your own from large transistors and would equate to what I imagine to be at least a brick of silicon. In other words, don't do it. You would be better off filtering the output of the buck converter instead which would still take quite a bit of effort due to the amperage required but large capacitors and inductors are easier than massive hunks of silicon.

Comment: Please google "The XY problem stack exchange" and read that question/answer, and see if you'd like to rephrase.  Would you mind if I ask why you think you need to drive your load at 320kW for 2 seconds?